# Any merit to the notion of limiting COVID19 vaccine only to those aged 60+ or with a comorbidity

Tags: covid-19

Last night I heard Peter Navarro, Trade Czar under the Trump administration, being interviewed on TV. He was plugging his new book. During the course of the sloppy interview, in which he and the interviewer were talking over each other, he mentioned in passing that the COVID-19 vaccines, as envisioned by the Trump administration, were intended only for those who were at risk of developing life-threatening symptoms, senior citizens and those with a comorbidity.

With an airborne respiratory virus like COVID-19, is there any benefit to leaving a large segment of the (US) population unvaccinated, allowing the virus to take its natural course? Could doing so have hastened the transition from pandemic to endemic, without overburdening the US health-care system or significantly increasing the rate of COVID-19 mortality, either in the US or worldwide?

Comment: That was their strategy: https://www.politico.com/news/2020/12/16/trump-appointee-demanded-herd-immunity-strategy-446408